# 's3cmd sync' only syncs files, does not recursively sync (FreeBSD py-s3cmd)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, s3cmd

I have tried many dozens of variations to coax this utility into behaving as its documentation claims it will (FreeBSD 10, py-s3cmd).

With this directory structure:

```
A
file1.txt
+ B
  + file2.txt
```

According to the documentation and the man page, the following command should recursively sync this entire tree:

```
s3cmd sync /local/A/ s3://com.foo.bar/mybucket/
```

However, the command only syncs file1.txt and nothing else. I have tried with the --recursive flag and it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user running the command did not have read access to the file. Once that user had permission, of course everything worked.